# Protecting DC GND from high voltages induced on mains PE

Tags: power-supply

In electrical vehicle supply equipment (EVSE) the Pilot signal GND is common with the PE conductor. An RCD (either 30mA AC, or 6mA DC + 30mA AC) is also included.

For making an external test of the RCD good functionality, a momentary short of the Live conductor to the PE, through a switch and a series resistor of some tenths kΩ to cause an AC current of 30mA is a common practice. The same applies to a DC test with a switch in series with a bridge rectifier and a resistor to cause a DC current of 6mA.

The problem arises from the momentary high voltage of the Live conductor that is conducted to the PE (and according to the signal GND) during the test, and that could destroy the sensitive electronic parts. What can I do to isolate only the AC part from the GND? And to keep a good DC coupling among PE and DC GND?

I have seen on the PCB of an industrial EVSE, on which the PE is also connected, a black SMT part without any marking that connects the PE to the signal GND, but it is impossible to find out what part it is.

One time, by mistake I got the output signal from the GND connector and not from the PE connector and the PCB damaged. In other words, I bypassed this black SMT part. I checked it with ohmmeter and shows almost 0 ohms. I checked some similar parts on the PCB and I got again 0 ohms, so I suppose this part is OK. What kind could be this part? An inductor? A ferrite bead? A MOV varistor?

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: that's a wall of text.

Comment: If the live is only connected to the PE through a resistor, the PE should never rise significantly above true Earth voltage.  If it does, there's something else wrong.